# System::Windows::Forms::Form::ShowDialog()

Tags: .net, c++, forms, showdialog

I have a 2 forms setup

my first form will call another form with the ShowDialog() method when I receive data from the serial port

ShowDialog() throws InvalidOperation with additionnal information "DragDrop registration did not succeed"

any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheesy google search answer...  but it seems to address your issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/269b8950-2ef9-483f-8124-e2725ffd5d83/